# Using T4MVC and Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

How to use **T4MVC** templates with **Kendo UI** helpers for *ASP.NET MVC*?

```
@(Html.Kendo()
  .Grid<SomeModel>()
  .Name("T4Grid")
  .Columns(col =>
  {
      col.Bound(wf => wf.Name);
      col.Bound(wf => wf.Description);
  })
  .DataSource(src => src
      .Ajax()
      .Read(read => read.Action(MVC.Area.Controller.Action())))) // <= an error here
```

I have an error message:

```
'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.CrudOperationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Action'
and the best extension method overload 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.NavigatableExtensions.Action(
Kendo.Mvc.INavigatable, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary)'
has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code to your question, as it might help to understand your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this [article](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnetmvcteam/posts/09-11-03/using-t4mvc-strongly-typed-helpers-with-telerik-extensions-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx) and modified the solution.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent;

public static class NavigationItemBuilderExtensions
{
    public static NavigationItemBuilder<TItem, TBuilder> Action<TItem, TBuilder>
        (this NavigationItemBuilder<TItem, TBuilder> instance, ActionResult action)
        where TItem : NavigationItem<TItem>
        where TBuilder : NavigationItemBuilder<TItem, TBuilder>, IHideObjectMembers
    {
        return Action<NavigationItemBuilder<TItem, TBuilder>>(instance, action);
    }

    public static CrudOperationBuilderBase<TBuilder> Action<TBuilder>
        (this CrudOperationBuilderBase<TBuilder> instance, ActionResult action)
        where TBuilder : CrudOperationBuilderBase<TBuilder>, IHideObjectMembers
    {
        return Action<CrudOperationBuilderBase<TBuilder>>(instance, action);
    }

    private static TResult Action<TResult>(dynamic instance, ActionResult action)
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
        }

        var actionResult = action as IT4MVCActionResult;
        if (actionResult == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "An argument action must implement IT4MVCActionResult interface.");
        }

        instance.Action(
            actionResult.Action,
            actionResult.Controller,
            actionResult.RouteValueDictionary);

        return instance;
    }
}
```

A usage shown below:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid<SomeModel>()
      .Name("T4Grid")
      .Columns(col =>
      {
          col.Bound(wf => wf.Name);
          col.Bound(wf => wf.Description);
      })
      .DataSource(src => src
          .Ajax()
          .Read(read => read.Action(MVC.SomeArea.SomeController.SomeAction()))))

@(Html.Kendo()
      .PanelBar()
      .Name("T4PanelBar")
      .Items(bar =>
      {
          bar.Add().Text("Index").Action(MVC.SomeArea.SomeController.SomeAction());
          bar.Add().Text("Another").Action(MVC.SomeArea.SomeController.SomeAction2());
      }))
```

Comment: @Vash, I can do it only tomorrow.